# Play Integrity API token produces IntegrityErrorCode.html#TOO_MANY_REQUESTS

Tags: integrity, safetynet, google-play-integrity-api

I'm trying to migrate from SafetyNet to Play Integrity API following googles documentation
https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/verdict#request. 
I'm building my request the same way they do in docs:

```
    Task<IntegrityTokenResponse> integrityTokenTask =
            integrityManager.requestIntegrityToken(
                            IntegrityTokenRequest.builder()
                                    .setCloudProjectNumber(CLOUD_PROJECT_NUMBER)
                                    .setNonce(Base64.encodeToString(NONCE_IN_BYTES, Base64.URL_SAFE | Base64.NO_WRAP))
                                    .build();
```

But when I'm trying to invoke token() on the result I get TOO_MANY_REQUESTS error even though I'm sending only one request.

```
integrityTokenTask.getResult().token();

An error occurred in main and is: -8: Integrity API error (-8): The calling app is making too many requests to the API and hence is throttled.
```

Play Integrity is properly set up in my Google Cloud Console.
Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play Integrity API must be enabled in Google Play Console, not Cloud console, if your app is on-Play. Please, specify your console where you setup PIA.

Comment: PIA is integrated into a sdk in my case, app I'm using for testing isn't and will not be on Play which, according to [docs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/setup), means that for api to work I have to add my cloud project number to the request.

Comment: Yes, it is true. But to make it work in the app - the app also must have PIA enabled, see https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/setup#sdks. If you update Play store to latest version and try to call your SDK from app again - do you see the same error now or new one? Thank you!

Comment: Well app was connected to the play console, which I had no idea about. So enabling the API there was a solution. Other solution is to change applicationId in your build.gradle, if your app is on Play Console but you don't want to or simply don't have access to enabling Integrity.

Answer (score 1):

**Play integrity API request quota is exhausted** which is initially 10000 requests/day. You can check the daily used quota [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/playintegrity.googleapis.com/quotas?). You have to fill out a request form to increase it. To request to change your app's usage tier, complete this [form](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/piaqr).

Comment: That was not the case, I commented solution under the first answer